# For the purpose of the Comprehend Languages spell, does beast speak (i.e. the language spoken by birds) count as a language?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, languages, animals

I got into an argument with somebody regarding whether or not an incomprehensible language spoken by an animal (or monstrosity, as we argued) counts as a language for the *Comprehend Languages* spell.

We know birds speak their own language(as in only birds can understand each other, with the exception of forest gnomes). Does such a beast language count as a language for the purpose of understanding?

Comment: “We know birds speak their own language.” Could you be more specific about what you are referring to?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Most animals don't speak any languages…

If you look at the "Languages" entry in their Monster Manual entries, no languages are listed. For example, the entry for the [raven](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16992-raven) says (MM, p. 335):

> **Languages** —

This is important, because being able to understand at least one language is often used as a measure of communication ability. For example, the description of the [thri-kreen](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1121699-thri-kreen) racial trait [Thri-Kreen Telepathy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/1121699-thri-kreen#Thri-kreenTraits) states:

> [...] A contacted creature doesn't need to share a language with you to understand your thoughts, but it must be able to understand at least one language. [...]

As a result, thri-kreen cannot use this feature to communicate with ravens: the ravens simply don't have the level of sapience required. Whatever method these birds use to communicate with each other, it is not a language in D&D terms (or in real-world terms, for that matter!).

This also means, if you want to understand what a raven is trying to communicate, you'll need to use a spell that doesn't specify languages. *Speak with animals* allows you to "comprehend and verbally communicate with beasts" without requiring that they speak or understand any language; this is presumably the expected way to communicate with animals like this.

### …though some do.

If you look at the stat block for the [giant owl](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/16889-giant-owl) (MM, p. 327), for example, you see that it speaks the Giant Owl language. Since this is an actual language, *comprehend languages* will let you understand it, and thri-kreen will be able to speak to giant owls telepathically.

So while most beasts don't speak any languages, you'll need to check the stat block for a particular one to be sure. A small handful are intelligent enough to mechanically have full languages of their own.

Comment: My related question about bestial language script: [Are bestial languages such as Giant Elk and Giant Owl written languages?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/185809/62294).

Comment: +1. The key here is that "language" is a specific thing in DnD. Meaning, something that is a "language" in the real world may not be a "language" in DnD terms.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes. I've always assumed that being a D&D language implies that Common (or English or whatever players are actually speaking at the table) can be translated to/from it without huge losses, including abstract concepts.  Real-world animal communication probably doesn't have that feature, regardless of whether people call it "whale language" or "bird language".

Comment: You may want to amend this answer to reference that players wishing to talk to animals are expected to use spells like Speak with Animals.